# Connect MTK6580 to PC, see in Device Manager but not in Explorer

Tags: android, iphone

Trying to connect  Andorid MTK6580 phone  and now I can't connect it to PC (W10), I see it perfectly as 2 drives in Device manager, but that's it.
Do I need to install or unhide something ? I have ESET antivirus too.

Tx Mario
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you selected "Connect as media device" (or something like that)?

Comment: Thanks Thomas,  Yes, I put one more pic.  Overall it's really crazy, is this b'z of this MT processor ? All other Androids are plug and play.  There are so much help on www, but it didn't work for me. I just need to make visible while it's ON, so not sure if I need that Loader which mentioned  everywhere....

Answer (score 0):

Just found that you need to select MTP, and it works just fine.  I updated photo with right option selected, it also tricky to find this option on MKT phones, you need to connect usb, then swipe done top to bring notification,  then you might need to swipe left, right to find USB connect info